# Parsing lines of a file as bash script parameters

Tags: bash

I have a file (`commands`) containing a list of commands to be executed with one command per line. I need to parse each line with my bash script (`main.sh`) to maintain the parameters intact, so that I can pass them to another bash script (`helper.sh`).

For example:

If `commands` contains:

```
echo -e "hello world\n"
cat path_to/some\ file
...
```

I need `main.sh` to be able to distinguish the parameters in each line as a bash script normally would (**desired results**):

```
for line 1:
command: echo
$1: -e
$2: hello world


for line 2:
command: cat
$1: path_to/some file
```

So that I can store them in an array and pass them to `helper.sh` properly.

So far, I've ended up with something like (**current results**):

```
for line 1:
command: echo
$1: -e
$2: "hello
$3: world
"

for line 2:
command: cat
$1: path_to/some\
$2: file
```

Comment: Can you provide your `commands` file as an example?

Comment: The problem is that once you "stringify" a command, it's really hard to unpack it (as bash would see it) without actually executing the command (with eval). You want to perform the [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) steps. I'm not aware of a tool or scripts that can do that.

Comment: Ah, I did figure out a way, but Charles closed this question. Shrug. The basis was to read the file with `while IFS= read -r line` and then extract the contents into an array with `declare -a words=($line)` -- variable is unquoted.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a convenient module, `shlex`, for this. Try something like:

```
$ cat shparse.py
import shlex
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    parts = shlex.split(line)
    print(f'command: {parts[0]}')
    argument_number = 1
    for argument in parts[1:]:
        print(f'${argument_number}: {argument}')
        argument_number += 1
$ cat commands.txt
echo -e "hello world\n"
cat path_to/some\ file
$ python3 shparse.py <commands.txt
command: echo
$1: -e
$2: hello world\n
command: cat
$1: path_to/some file
```